# Why does using a timeout apparently lose reference of the this variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Why does this:

```
myelements.mouseenter(function() {  
  clearTimeout(globaltimeoutvar);
  globaltimeoutvar = setTimeout(function() {
  var index = myelements.index(this);
    console.log(index); // -1
  }, 150);
});
```

log `-1`, while this:

```
myelements.mouseenter(function() {
  var index = myelements.index(this);
  clearTimeout(globaltimeoutvar);
  globaltimeoutvar = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(index); // 0, 1, 2, 3, what ever
  }, 150);
});
```

logs the correct index?

Or: does any reference/ event data get broken when trying to access it in a timeout callback?

Comment: `this` inside `function` points to object, for which `function` was called. For `setTimeout` this object is `window`.

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zquyf9ch/).

Comment: @Regent will you post an answer?

Comment: Alex, Bhushan Kawadkar has already posted this as an answer :) So you can accept his answer.

Comment: but you were first :) not hunting for rep?

Comment: Alex, the main purpose is to help people and to learn something new for myself :) I post my correct comments as answers when there are no correct answers and done work is big enough. I suspect that thanking user by voting up 1-3 his random answers is forbidden in SO, but posting 4th same answer is really useless :) At least I'm glad that my comment was helpful to you.

Comment: great to have you on SO, thanks again mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You can store `$(this)` in a variable and use it inside `setTimeOut`

As @Regent said,`this` refers to object for which function get called and hence `this` is refering to `window`

```
myelements.mouseenter(function() {  
  var myelementsThis = $(this);
  clearTimeout(globaltimeoutvar);
  globaltimeoutvar = setTimeout(function() {
  var index = myelements.index(myelementsThis);
    console.log(index); // -1
  }, 150);
});
```

Comment: this does indeed work, normally when storing this for context the keyword `that` is used.  this is just a common convention for naming though and not a specification.

Answer (score 1):

`this` depen on how the function is invoked.

1. In a global context `this` is `window`.
2. If it is invoked as an object method `this` is the object.

(really both as are object method case, but in the first case the object is `window`)

In your first sample `this` is `window` because `setTimeout()` is actually `window.setTimeout()`. In your second sample `this` is your object `myelements`.

See the sample below:

```
var globalFunc = function(){ return this
};

if(globalFunc() === window){
  alert("this is window");
}

var someObject = {};
someObject.method = function(){ return this };
if(someObject.method() === someObject){
  alert("this is the object");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To further explain what @Bhushan and @abc123 are saying, the way to have `this` scoped properly is to ensure that the context is correct. Give this a try:

```
myelements.mouseenter(function() {  

  var that = this; // Store the correct context in a variable.

  clearTimeout(globaltimeoutvar);
  globaltimeoutvar = setTimeout(function() {

  var index = myelements.index(that); // Scoped correctly to the myelements object.
  var wrongIndex = myelements.index(this); // Scoped to the window object via setTimeout.

    console.log(index); // Correct value.
  }, 150);
});
```